# .Find multiple times

Tags: vba, ms-word

So I need to do a .Find and If true then Return Values into a cell then do another .Find.
What I have so far work for Text1 but then returns False for Text2. Was thinking I needed to reset the .Found value somehow?

```
With wrdDoc
        With .Range.Find
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Text = "text1"
        .Execute
    If .Found = True Then
      Cells(resultRow, 1).Value = strFileName
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Text = "text2"
        .Execute
        If .Found = True Then
          MsgBox "This document contains the word2"
```

I'm a little new to this so I must just be missing some rules around .Range.Find

Comment: You could just use an if statement if find 1 is true and find 2 is true

Comment: The problem is that, having found "text1", that becomes the range you're searching for "text2" - which obviously won't be found there.

Comment: yes that makes sense to me macropod. is there a way to reset the value to .Range?